# PrintWriter writes blank file

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I want to change the score of the user, but instead of overwriting the file with new scores, it just makes an empty file.
The lines are written like this: "username-password-wins-losses-ties"

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.txt"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("users.txt"));
        String[] tab = null;
        String zlepek = "";
        while(br.readLine()!=null) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            tab = line.split("-");
            int countLoss = Integer.parseInt(tab[3]+plusLoss);
            int countWin = Integer.parseInt(tab[2]+plusWin);
            int countTie = Integer.parseInt(tab[4]+plusTie);
            if(tab[0].equals(loginUser.user)) {
                String newScore = (tab[0] + "-" + tab[1] + "-" + countWin + "-" + countLoss + "-" + countTie + "\n");
                zlepek = zlepek+newScore;
            } else {
                String oldScore = (tab[0] + "-" + tab[1] + "-" + tab[2] + "-" + tab[3] + "-" + tab[4] + "\n");
                zlepek = zlepek+oldScore;
            }   
        }
        pw.print(zlepek);
        pw.close();
        br.close();

        plusWin = 0;
        plusLoss = 0;
        plusTie = 0;

    } catch(IOException e) {}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are skipping the first line and every odd lines, change the code like below

```
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            // code
    }
```

also you are reading and writing on a same file, you can't read and write simultaneously on a same file. If you want you can write it to a temporary file and rename it later.

If you want write on the same file, you have to close the reader before writing, see below

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.txt"));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String zlepek = "";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            zlepek = // logic to get value
            sb.append(zlepek).append("\n");
        }
        br.close();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("users.txt")); // pass true to append
        pw.print(sb);
        pw.close();
```

Comment: I replaced my code with yours, but the file is still empty after I write to it.

Comment: Updated answer, Do you've any text in input file?

Comment: First I register a user, and save it into the "users.txt" file. The line looks like this: "username-password-wins-losses-ties" (user-pass-0-0-0). Then I play the game and this code should put all of changed and unchanged lines into "zlepek" string. At the end, it should paste whatever is in the "zlepek" string back into the file, overwriting the existing text. Instead, it just replaces everything with a blank file.

Comment: If you want write on the same file, you have to close the reader before writing, see updated answer

Comment: Seems to return an error when trying to run this code: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
The file seems to not have changed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line `while(br.readLine()!=null)`, you read the line but didnt save it, so it doesnt know where it is and the line will always be empty after you read the line and dont save it.

try to remove this `String line = br.readLine();` and read it in the while. define the `String line;` and `while( (line = br.readLine()) != null){ // do something}`

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        String[] tab = null;
        String line = null;
        tab = line.split("-");
        int countLoss = Integer.parseInt(tab[3]+plusLoss);
        int countWin = Integer.parseInt(tab[2]+plusWin);
        int countTie = Integer.parseInt(tab[4]+plusTie);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.txt"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String zlepek = "";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(tab[0].equals(loginUser.user)) {
                 String newScore = (tab[0] + "-" + tab[1] + "-" + countWin + "-" + countLoss + "-" + countTie + "\n");
                 zlepek = zlepek+newScore;
                } else {
                   String oldScore = (tab[0] + "-" + tab[1] + "-" + tab[2] + "-" + tab[3] + "-" + tab[4] + "\n");
                    zlepek = zlepek+oldScore;
                }
            sb.append(zlepek).append("\n");
        }
        br.close();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("users.txt")); // pass true to append
        pw.print(sb);
        pw.close();

        plusWin = 0;
        plusLoss = 0;
        plusTie = 0;

    } catch(IOException e) {}
}
```